# Proportional editing on UV map

Tags: uv, scale

I am a beginner and I'm currently following these tutorials on Youtube in order to finish my model but I am stuck!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8UH_WU23Io - this is the tutorial on how to UV map the eyes. 
It seems quite easy, but my issue is that at that part where I should scale the selected part of the mesh on the UV map with the proportional editing tool.

When i attempt to do it, 
1. The ring that should aid me as to deciding how big the "influence" should be does not appear (despite me having enabled the tool) and
2. If I, then, try to move or scale the selected area, the whole mesh moves with it.

This results in the eye that I'm creating having several irises and pupils which is, of course, not what I want.

Does anyone know what could be the possible source of this?
Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess..The proportional editing circle might have been too big and is not showing in your screen. If this is the case, it also explains why your entire mesh is moving because the circle is encompassing everything. To rectify this, scale down the circle by scrolling up the mouse wheel.

Comment: I read that on other posts too, however, when I do that I basically zoom in and out :/

Comment: Please share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here. Please pack all external data and save the blend file before uploading https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MbCb.png

Comment: Actually never mind, you were absolutely right and I didn't go back enough to see how terribly big the editing circle was i just played around and saw. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad I could help :) I wrote the same as an answer. Please mark it as accepted ✅. That way it wont show up in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proportional editing circle might have been too big and is not showing in your screen. If this is the case, it also explains why your entire mesh is moving because the circle is encompassing everything. To rectify this, scale down the circle by scrolling up the mouse wheel.